# Why does SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) throw error code 20?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, verify

I am receiving a certificate via `SSL_get_peer_certificate()` and can read information about that certificate via `X509_get_subject_name(cert)`. That's why I am pretty sure that from this side everything works right. I also updated my CA-Certificates and called `SSL_set_default_verify_paths(context)`.

I tried this with several websites (google.de, openssl.org, ...). I have really no idea why I don't get the return value 0 (=X509_V_OK).

I also tried `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` including `c_rehash` the directory of the ca-certificates. That's why the CA-Certificates should be loaded correct into the SSL_CTX. Still Error Code 20 from `SSL_get_verify_result()`

**UPDATE**

If I try the same with the command line utilites of OpenSSL (`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/` I get as a result return code 0 (ok). How can this be possible?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue.